# netsh command not found - what package do I need to install?

Tags: command-line

I get this error when I run `netsh http show iplisten`:

```
netsh: command not found
```

What package I should install?

Comment: `netsh` is a windows tool, You can't use it on Ubuntu. But as an alternative tools the `ip` command from `iproute2` package may be helpful for you